# two separate systems controlled by one controller (wifi)

Tags: heating, cooling

I have two separate systems with two separate thermostats, cooling on the second floor and heating on the first. Is there a way to have a "main" thermostat on the first floor and control the cooling via a wifi controller and the thermostat controlling the heat from the first floor?

Comment: There are various smart thermostat systems out there that do this exact thing. A quick google query can point you in the right direction for your needs. These thermostats can be linked via wifi and controlled with an app on your phone as the "wifi controller".

Comment: You're not likely to find _one_ thermostat that can control both systems simultaneously.  Your question might be a little unclear, but a single thermostat will not control heat and cooling at the same time.  If you only run one at a time, you might have some options.

Comment: Why not get two smart thermostats and control both from the same app?  If you have 2 systems it better for them to operate from individual thermostats.  What your asking tho, sure it could be accomplished with some relay magic, but why would anyone do that?  It’s not a logical path to follow, the areas likely don’t heat and cool at identical rates.

Comment: What sort of heating system are we talking about here?